# Models haskell Beginner

Tags: haskell, logic, models

Hi there im new to haskell and im stuck on this Question, which is given a formula, it returns the model of that formula, where the Model is a valuation which makes the formula true. An example would be model eg `==[[("p",True),("q",True)],[("p",True),("q",False)]]`

Using this definiton of Prop:

```
          data Prop = Falsum   -- a contradiction, or
         |Var Variable -- a  variable,or 
         |Not Prop -- a negation of a formula, or
         |Or Prop Prop -- a disjunction of two formulae,or
        |And Prop Prop -- a conjunction of two formulae, or 
        |Imp Prop Prop -- a conditional of two formulae
          deriving (Eq,show)
```

And Valuations:

```
valuations ::[Variable]->[Valuation]
valuations [] = [[]]
valuations (v:vs) = map ((v,True):) ds ++ map ((v,False):) ds 
 where ds = valuations vs
```

So far I have this code:

```
models :: Prop-> Prop-> Bool
models p q = and $ valuations (p == q)
```

However it doesn't seem to be working and I've been stuck on this for a while so was wondering if anyone can help out?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve?  What question are you stuck on exactly?  What is a model, what kind of formula?

Comment: What is the definition of `Prop`. What is `valuations`? The final return type of `model` being `Bool` doesn't match your description that a model is a list of bindings which make a proposition true.

Comment: @bheklilr the type of formula that i would be passing in is a propostional logic type of formula and the part im stuck on, is that you have to produce the the the values that all produce true of the given formula,So basically the problem is to make a truth table and then filter  out all the false answers,Im just not to sure how to do that

Comment: This same problem has been more completely described in a more recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038899/haskell-beginner-without-a-clue

Answer (score 1):

This is the same homework question that I am trying to answer. It appears that your understanding of the question is somewhat incorrect. They type line for models should be:

models :: Prop -> [Valuation]

You are trying to return only the formulas that give an overall evaluation of True.

example = And p (Or q (Not q))

When 'example' is passed to the models function it produces the following list:

[[("p",True),("q",True)],[("p",True),("q",False)]]

This is because an And statement can only ever evaluate to True if both inputs are True. The second input of the And statement, (Or q (Not q)) always evaluates to True as an Or statement always evaluates to True if one of the inputs is True. This is always the case in our example as our Or can be either (Or True (Not True)) or (Or False (Not False)) and both will always evaluate to True. So as long as the first input evaluates to True then the overall And statement will evaluate to True.

Valuations has to be passed a list of Variables and you have a function that does this. If you pass it just the Var "p" then you get [[("p",True)],[("p",False)]] as those are the only two possible combinations.

What you (we) are wanting is to pass the Valuations list and only return those that evaluate to True. For example if your list was just Var "p" and your formula was Not p then only the second list, [("p",False)], would be returned as p only evaluates to True when you assign False to Not p as Not False = True.

Almost forgot, all the possible combinations for And p (Or q (Not q)) --remember (Or q (Not q) is True

And False (False (Not False))    = And False True = False -- [("p",False),("q",False)]]
And False True  (True (Not True) = And False True = False -- [("p",False),("q",True)]]
And True  (False (Not False))    = And True  True = True  -- [("p",True),("q",False)]]
And True  (True (Not True)       = And True  True = True  -- [("p",True),("q",True)]]

As you can see the bottom two lines are the ones the homework question says will be returned. I just haven't worked out how to finish it myself yet.  I can get the full list of [Valuations] I just can't work out how to get only the True ones and discard the ones that evaluate False.