# Haskell Beginner without a Clue

Tags: list, haskell

It took me a while to even work out what this question was looking for. I have to return only those propositions that give an overall evaluation of True. Our example is And p (Or q (Not q)) and I know that p has to be True and q can be either True or False. To achieve our goal we have been given a few functions to start with.

```
type Variable = String
type Valuation = [(Variable, Bool)]

data Prop = Falsum         -- a contradiction, or
          | Var Variable   -- a variable, or
          | Not Prop       -- a negation of a formula, or
          | Or  Prop Prop  -- a disjunction of two formulae, or
          | And Prop Prop  -- a conjunction of two formulae, or
          | Imp Prop Prop  -- a conditional of two formulae.
            deriving (Eq, Show)

example = And p (Or q (Not q))

vars :: Prop -> [Variable]
vars = nub . vars'
    where
      vars' Falsum    = []
      vars' (Var v)   = [v]
      vars' (Not f)   = vars' f
      vars' (Or  f g) = vars' f ++ vars' g
      vars' (And f g) = vars' f ++ vars' g 
      vars' (Imp f g) = vars' f ++ vars' g 

eval :: Valuation -> Prop -> Bool
eval val Falsum    = False
eval val (Var v)   = case (lookup v val) of
                       Nothing -> error ("Unbound variable: " ++ v)
                       Just t  -> t 
eval val (Not f)   = not (eval val f)
eval val (Or  f g) = (eval val f) || (eval val g)
eval val (And f g) = (eval val f) && (eval val g)
eval val (Imp f g) = eval val (Or (Not f) g)

valuations :: [Variable] -> [Valuation]
valuations []     = [[]]
valuations (v:vs) = map ((v,True):) ds ++ map ((v,False):) ds 
    where ds = valuations vs
```

I now have to write a models function and I worked out that the typeline has to be

```
models :: Prop -> [Valuations]
```

as my example must return the list of Valuations that are evaluate to True which is:
models example == [[("p",True)("q",True)],[("p",True)("q",False)]]

I know that vars returns the list of variables without duplicates, in this case ["p","q"], and that passing the result from vars into valuations produces the list of all possible outcomes of applying True and False to both "p" and "q". So far I can only get the first output of this list to evaluate using the evals function. Here's my code:

```
models :: Prop -> Bool
models form = eval v form where (v:vs) = valuations (vars form)
```

I have tried to change the code to evaluate the rest of vs but I keep getting an error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type '[Bool]' with actual type 'Bool'
```

Here's my altered code:

```
models :: Prop -> [Bool]
models form = eval v form : eval vs form where (v:vs) = valuations (vars form)
```

Ideally I believe I would want to discard the eval results rather than keep them in a list and only return those valuations which evaluate to True. I'm just stuck on how to recursively evaluate the rest of vs.

I believe once I can evaluate all elements in my list using the evals function then I can just add the ones that evaluate to True using some form of equality assignment, such as:

```
where finalList == True =
```

Alas, that doesn't even look close to being correct.

Any help with my logic would be helpful. Oh and an explanation as to how I can recursive evaluate the rest of the list would be appreciated.

Comment: 'Haskell Beginner without a Clue' - don't worry, that's normal.  With more experience, things wil get worse:)

Comment: Were all the functions provided or did you come up with some of that?

Comment: Yeah I tried to add homework to the description line but it wouldn't let me so I changed homework to "without a clue". All the code in the main block is what we were given to work with, all the rest (the stuff that doesn't work) was written by me. I'm really more interested in the logic, i.e. how to work out the solution, rather than a direct answer as I think that will help me more. I always seem to come up with the same error when trying to recursively call lists, that is the first element evaluates but the rest are usually of type list, i.e. expected Char when given [Char].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want `models :: Prop -> [Valuation]` like you started to write. Models will return every `Valuation` that satisfies the proposition. Starting with something close to what you had

```
models form = valuations (vars form)
```

gets us halfway there; it has the correct type, `Prop -> [Valuation]`. This just lists every `Valuation` for the variables in `form`. What we'd like is to have only those results which satisfy the proposition. These can be determined by your `eval` function.

```
models :: Prop -> [Valuation]
models form = filter satisfies (valuations (vars form))
    where satisfies val = eval val form
```

To run this, we need to fix your example so it compiles, and maybe add a couple examples of my own:

```
example = And (Var "p") (Or (Var "q") (Not (Var "q")))

main = do
    print $ models Falsum
    print $ models example
    print $ models $ And (Var "p") (Not (Var "p"))
    print $ models $ Or (Var "p") (Not (Var "p"))
```

This outputs

```
[]
[[("p",True),("q",True)],[("p",True),("q",False)]]
[]
[[("p",True)],[("p",False)]]
```

Now, we might also want a function that checks to see if there exists any `Valuation` that satisfies the proposition. This would take a proposition and return a boolean.

```
satisfiable :: Prop -> Bool
```

We can easily write this in terms of `models`

```
satisfiable :: Prop -> Bool
satisfiable = not . null . models
```

For the same four examples

```
main = do
    print $ satisfiable Falsum
    print $ satisfiable example
    print $ satisfiable $ And (Var "p") (Not (Var "p"))
    print $ satisfiable $ Or (Var "p") (Not (Var "p"))
```

This outputs

```
False
True
False
True
```

Comment: Since this is clearly homework, and you're struggling with `filter`ing a list, I'd suggest you try to write the function `alwaysTrue :: Prop -> Bool`. It should return `True` if every possible `Valuation` evaluates to `True`, and `False` otherwise. `satisfiable :: Prop -> Bool` can also be written in a similar way to `alwaysTrue`.

Comment: Thanks Cirdec it never occurred to me to use filter in this way. Well at least not directly as I was thinking of using my evaluation as the predicate of a list comprehension once I got it recursively calling each element. Having checked the source code for filter on Hoogle for the first time I noticed that it is a list comprehension itself. I still have to mull over the where statement to fully understand how it is working but I think I have a clear idea of it now. Thanks again! I did try to type homework into the description but it wouldn't let me and since it was after 2 a.m. I just left it.